# jquery mobile ajax call error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, https

I am facing  " net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE " error when i am trying to connect to a particular server through jquery mobile ajax call. The server is in https.
How to solve?
I went through various stackoverflow questions, but I am not getting a clear concept regarding this error. If i have to install security certificate then how to do that ?

Any step by step procedure to solve this problem will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what does ssllabs.com says about the domain you wants to call?

Comment: Its showing overall rating F and a bunch of other details . . . What does this F means ? Does the server having problem?

Comment: F is the worse. A is good, B is ok, C and under need to be fixed ASAP. If you see "chain issues", you should fix that too, It means some client can"t connect.